# Centering footer contents with css in html5

Tags: css, html

I am re-writing a website to HTML5, and I am having some problems with centering the contents of the footer.

My footer HTML is pretty simple

```
<footer> Copyright </footer>
```

and the css is

```
footer {
    margin: auto;
    height: 330px;
    background-color: #1e2127;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

but the content is not centered with the rest of the page.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**
I don't want to center the text inside the footer, only the footer it self (so it will align with the rest of the page), but I want the background to fill out the entire page.

Comment: 5 answer just in 3  minutes :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want the footer centred horizontally, in which case `margin: auto;` requires a specified *width* to centre automatically:

```
footer {
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
  /* other styles */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

hope this is what you want [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/E25JV/)

```
footer {
    margin: auto;
    height: 330px;
    background-color: #1e2127;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align:center; //to align the text in center
}​
```

Comment: @Jack thanx for the appreciation :)

Comment: Truly deserved answer, its  fast accurate and with demo too!!

Comment: I perhaps did not make it clear, that I wanted the footer to be centered, but not the text inside. +1 for tool, that's cool!

Answer (score 3):

You haven't given the footer a width, which means it will default to 100%, with the text left aligned.  Add text-align: center to center the text, or add a width to center the whole footer.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `text-align:center` to make the content center aligned.

Answer (score 1):

set smth like that:

```
<footer><span>Copyright<span></footer>
```

and css:

```
footer {
    margin: auto;
    height: 330px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1e2127;
    color: #ffffff;
}

footer span {
    display:block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 330px;
    background-color: #1e2127;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

margin: 0 auto will work if parent container have some width 
else you can try putting `text-align:center;`